# Java car class for beginner

Tags: java, class

I must Implement a class Car with the following properties. A car has a certain fuel efficiency (measured in miles/gallon or liters/km—pick one) and a certain amount of fuel in the gas tank. The efficiency is specified in the constructor, and the initial fuel level is 0. Supply a method drive that simulates driving the car for a certain distance, reducing the amount of gasoline in the fuel tank. Also supply methods getGasInTank, returning the current amount of gasoline in the fuel tank, and addGas, to add gasoline to the fuel tank.

I have created a class for the car and a test program to plug some values in and when i run the program all i get returned is the addGas value that i put in. the computation for the miles per gallon will not run and i do not understand why. as you can probably tell i am VERY new at java and any help on the issue is much appreciated.

```
    public class CarTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Car richCar = new Car(49);

    richCar.addGas(15);
    richCar.drive(150);
    System.out.println(richCar.getGas());
  }
}





    /**
A car can drive and consume fuel
*/
public class Car
{
/**
  Constructs a car with a given fuel efficiency
  @param anEfficiency the fuel efficiency of the car
*/
public Car(double mpg)
{
  milesPerGallon = mpg;
  gas = 0;
  drive = 0;
}

 /** Adds gas to the tank.
   @param amount the amount of fuel added
 */
 public void addGas(double amount)
 {
  gas = gas + amount;
 }

 /**
   Drives a certain amount, consuming gas
   @param distance the distance driven
 */
 public void drive(double distance)
 {
  drive = drive + distance;
 }

 /**
   Gets the amount of gas left in the tank.
   @return the amount of gas
  */

 public double getGas()
 {
  double mpg;
  double distance;
  distance = drive;
  mpg = gas * milesPerGallon / distance;
  return gas;
 }

  private double drive;
  private double gas;
  private double milesPerGallon;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried "running the program in your head" or using a debugger?

Comment: The `drive()` method should probably increment the odometer while also decrementing the gas tank.  `getGas()` should simply report the current fuel level, just as your fuel gauge would.  Fuel gauge on a car doesn't car about how much fuel you filled up with (in the life time of the car), nor does it care about how far you've driven (in the life time of the car).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining some ideas...

```
/**
Drives a certain amount, consuming gas
@param distance the distance driven
*/
public void drive(double distance)
{
    drive = drive + distance;
    gas = gas - (distance / milesPerGallon);
}

/**
Gets the amount of gas left in the tank.
@return the amount of gas
*/

public double getGas()
{
    return gas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's *computing* it just fine.  Your method is only *returning* the one value for gas, though.

This could use some clean-up; I'd suggest getting rid of all of the cruft, and just returning the calculation.

```
public double calculateGas() {
    return (gas * milesPerGallon) / drive;
}
```

Comment: The `MPG` of the car is set when the car is instantiated.  The gas level is what needs to be calculated (ideally in the `drive` method, I think).

Answer (score 0):

Your test program only calls three methods:

```
richCar.addGas(15);
richCar.drive(150);
System.out.println(richCar.getGas());
```

Let's take a look at what each one does.

`addGas(15)` modifies your gas instance variable.

`drive(150)` only executes the line `drive = drive + distance;`

`getGas()` seems to do a couple things, more than expected (one would expect it just returns `gas` but it also calculates and stores latest mpg value). But if you check the code of `getGas()` gas is never modified, only returned.

So you called three methods, and within those three executions gas is only modified once, when you set it to the value of 15 with `richCar.addGas(15)`.

It would seem most simple if the `drive(int)` method modifys `gas` based on some set mpg value, instead of only keeping track of how many miles were driven, and then you could have `drive()` simply just return `gas`.

That means you would also get rid of modifying `mpg` in `getGas()`, which is good, because that value is needed no matter what to calculate how much gas is used. You could perhaps introduce a `actualMpg` value if you had some more logic that changed how much gas is used but you don't have that yet.

Answer (score -1):

From what it looks like your problem lies here

```
public double getGas()
{
double mpg;
double distance;
distance = drive;
mpg = gas * milesPerGallon / distance;
return gas;
}
```

you are doing a calculation to mpg however you are returning the gas property at the end.

It doesn't actually seem like you are changing the value of gas anywhere except for when you first add it.